# xlsxwriter set num_format = "0!.0," but when i open it by excel, the format show is 0!!.0,

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()
ws.set_column('B:B', 30)

num=1234.52

num_formats = (
   '0.00',
   '#,##0.00',
   '0.00E+00',
   '##0.0E+0',
   '₹#,##0.00',
    '0!.0,'
)
ws.write('A1', 'Formatted Number')
ws.write('B1', 'Format')

row = 1
for fmt in num_formats:
   format = wb.add_format({'num_format': fmt})
   ws.write_number(row, 0, num, format)
   ws.write_string(row, 1, fmt)
   row += 1
wb.close()
```

But when I open this excel by office, the format is wrong, like this:

[image]

The num_format has been set to `0!!.0`,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: The format is `0!.0,` for me so seems it might be a local issue.

Comment: but when I set the format = 0!.0,  in excel it shows right.

Comment: I opened the created workbook in Excel 365, 2013 and libreOffice, all show the format with a single Exclamation point. You can unzip the xlsx file and check the sharedStrings.xml and syles.xml files see what they show it as after the file is created.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your sample code I get the expected result:

[image]

However, when I resave the file with Excel and look at the internal contents I see that it is storing the format as `"0\!.0,"`. So maybe try that instead.